# Crystal newbie needs assistance

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to count all employees in each dept and only display those departments that have more than 3 employees.
I'm totally clueless on how to do this.
I tried an If, Then but Crystal keeps telling me I need a 'then'
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You're not giving us much to work with.  Can you edit your post and give us some more detail? How is your report structured (i.e. groupings)?  Where did you put this code and what is the code exactly?

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you have to group by the department
- Then Create the summary for employee.`Rightclick on Employee->Insert->Summary->select count from the calculate this summary.`
- you have to suppress the detail section,and write the formula in the
  suppression `Count(EmployeeName)>=3`
- Then save this formula.

THus youe problem is solved.